# How to manipulate a string, variable in shell

Tags: shell, unix

Hei everyone!

I have this variable in shell containing paths separated by
a space:

```
LINE="/path/to/manipulate1 /path/to/manipulate2"
```

I want to add additional path string in the beginning of the string and as well right after the space so that the variable will have the result something like this:

```
LINE="/additional/path1/to/path/to/manipulate1 /additional/path2/to/path/to/manipulate2"
```

I tried this one but only get the old paths

```
#!/bin/bash

LINE="/path/to/one /path/to/two"
NEW_PATH=`echo $LINE |  sed "s/^\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\)/\/add1\1 \/add2\2/"`
echo "$NEW_PATH"
```

Any help appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what you want to add? What is `path1` in the first case and `path2` in the second case? Or did you mean to add the same for both?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually, just want to know how to add something in front of the string and something else after the space.

Comment: Yeah, I got it after a re-read. Haven't finished my morning coffee yet.

Comment: Can I put a directory with a space in your filesystem?  Can I?  Pleeease?

Answer (score 2):

This of courses messes with any previous arguments you might need to keep.

```
set $LINE
LINE="/additional/path1$1 /additional/path2$2"
```

Tested in bash/dash/ksh.

**Edit:** If keeping the original arguments is needed, this might be useful:

```
orig=$@
<stuff from above>
set $orig
```

Answer (score 1):

```
firstPath=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f1)
secondPath=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f2)

firstPath="/additional/path1/to$firstPath"
secondPath="/additional/path2/to$secondPath"
```

Comment: @user558134: Remember to upvote those answers that prove useful to your problem, also, mark as accepted the one that solves it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ test="/sbin /usr/sbin /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/X11R6/bin"

$ test2=$(for i in $test; do echo "/newroot${i}"; done)

$ echo $test2
/newroot/sbin /newroot/usr/sbin /newroot/bin /newroot/usr/bin /newroot/usr/local/bin /newroot/usr/X11R6/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bash:

If the additions are the same for each part:

```
LINE="/path/to/manipulate1 /path/to/manipulate2"
array=($LINE)
LINE=${array[@]/#//additional/path/to/}
```

If they are different:

```
LINE="/path/to/manipulate1 /path/to/manipulate2"
array=($LINE)
array[0]=/additional/path1/to${array[0]}
array[1]=/additional/path2/to${array[1]}
LINE=${array[@]}
```

Or, more flexibly:

```
LINE="/path/to/manipulate1 /path/to/manipulate2"
array=($LINE)
parts=(/additional/path1/to /additional/path2/to)
if (( ${#array[@]} == ${#parts[@]} ))
then
    for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++))
    do
        array[i]=${parts[i]}${array[i]}
    done
fi
LINE=${array[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NEW_PATH=`echo $LINE |  sed "s/^\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\)/\/add1\1 \/add2\2/"`
```

results in NEW_PATH =

/add1/path/to/manipulate1 /add2/path/to/manipulate2

Comment: Might want to escape those backticks or use `$(...)`

Comment: I tried this one: NEW_PATH=$(echo $LINE |  sed "s/^\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\)/\/add1\1 \/add2\2/") but no new path

Comment: did you try with the back tick character? I'm using the line i've sent you in bash (with the backticks) and it works

Comment: I tried this again and only get the old paths, not the new ones

Comment: could you paste here the script?

Comment: LINE="/path/to/one /path/to/two"
NEW_PATH=`echo $LINE |  sed "s/^\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\)/\/add1\1 \/add2\2/"`
echo "$NEW_PATH"

Comment: the sed expression is missing the escaping around the ( and the ) character

Comment: I've cut and pasted your code and I get a perfect result :(. Look this cut & paste from putty (the script is called "b"): localhost ~ # ./b
/add1/path/to/one /add2/path/to/two

Comment: tested in other 3 server (all with linux) and works in every one

Comment: I am testing on mac with terminal, still doesn't add the new path